# Getting correct data from a list would a for loop be best practice?

Tags: apex

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my question. I have a simple call to the recordType object that will have to results. The reason I have two results is because I need to verify of the opportunity has a certain type of record id and if so then I will create a serviceContract with a certain recordtypeID. Simple enough, however governor limits scare me right now. Here is the code below.

```
RecordType[] RecHyperStream = [SELECT 
                                    name, Description, id, SobjectType, BusinessProcessId          
                               FROM 
                                    RecordType 
                               WHERE
                                   (SobjectType='Opportunity' AND Description='HyperStream Services') 
                                   OR 
                                   (SobjectType='ServiceContract' AND Description='This is the record type assigned to HyperStream Agreement')
                               ];
```

In order to differentiate the two do I need to do a for Loop?

```
for(integer i =0; i < RecHyperStream.size(); i++)
  if(RecHyperStream[i].SobjectType == 'Opportunity')
     //put in a variable for opp
  else
     //put in a variable for serviceContract
```

Or is there a cleaner and simpler way that does not require a for-loop?

THanks again for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would not recommend using the recordtype description to filter since that could easily be changed. You can use the developername instead. 
There's really no cleaner way to distinguish than going through a loop.

You should not have any issues with governor limits because you are getting the recordtypes in one query.

```
list<RecordType> RecHyperStream = [SELECT name, Description, id, SobjectType, BusinessProcessId FROM RecordType WHERE (SobjectType='Opportunity' AND DeveloperName='HyperStream') OR (SobjectType='ServiceContract' AND DeveloperName='HyperStream')];

//putting it in a map is so that if you have more 'HyperStream' recordtypes you can handle them.
map<String,RecordType> recordTypeByObject = new map<String,RecordType>();
for(RecordType r : RecHyperStream ) recordTypeByObject.put(r.sobjectType,r);
```

Comment: Good idea grigri, I will use the map instead and make a for loop with two if statements, this way i can just manage the serviceContract and the opportunity

Answer (score 2):

http://www.salesforcefast.com/2012/03/look-up-record-type-ids-with-no-queries.html

You can use describe call here instead of query and this will reduce your query.

Always for record types prefer record type infos

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> RT = R.getRecordTypeInfos();
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_recordTypeInfo_methods

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohith, I am not familiar enough with this method and I will definitely investigate this further.

Comment: Not sure I'd agree with using record type infos preferentially, primarily due to the fact they're grouped by record type label not developer which means things always break when people update the record type label.

Comment: @Ralph There are disadvantages with not using it as it consumes queries .Certainly it will depend on situation and may be we can make admin aware of consequences of not changing labels .

Comment: Agreed, but I'd counter that the governor limits for describes is smaller than the query limits.